# How to escape for MYSQL queries from Ruby on Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, escaping

When searching the MYSQL database for a Rails 2.3.14 app, I need to escape the search string appropriately so I can search for strings containing single-quotes (apostrophes). What's the best way to do this? I'm using the `mysql` gem, in case that matters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use ActiveRecord's `quote` method (e.g. `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote("string with ' apostrophe")`), but ActiveRecord's query methods already escape your SQL for you.  For example:

```
a = "string with ' apostrophe"
ModelName.where("field1 = ?", a)
```

will change "string with ' apostrophe" to "string with '' apostrophe"

Comment: This is good for short queries, but for more complex queries it actually gets easier to use the SQL more directly. I'm looking at a case where I search in five different tables, and it gets very hard to track which variable is matched to which part of the query using this syntax.

Comment: Look Into scopes.  They let you break up your query into logical chunks,  and then chain them as necessary. It's much cleaner

Comment: We do have scopes. Separately: the app in question is also using raw SQL queries instead of Rails SQL methods as a performance consideration, so I won't be switching this code back to the ActiveRecord methods.

Comment: I'd still go with ActiveRecord's quote method to be database agnostic

Comment: Issue for me is performing a `like` query. `scope :like, -> (filter) { where("namespace like ? OR resource like ? OR owner like ?", some_strings)}`. If `%` is not escaped, then user can perform funny queries I guess.

Comment: The quote method is viable when using ActiveRecord::Base.connection#exec directly to run raw sql for a given reason.

Answer (score 10):

Rails [quotes strings](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.0/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb#L82) as follows:

```ruby
# Quotes a string, escaping any ' (single quote) and \ (backslash) characters.
def quote_string(s)
  s.gsub(/\\/, '\&\&').gsub(/'/, "''") # ' (for ruby-mode)
end
```

Answer (score 8):

When using the `mysql` gem, you gain the method `Mysql.escape_string()`. Use as follows:

```
search_terms = Mysql.escape_string("it's working!")
conditions = [ "table1.name LIKE '%#{search_terms}%'" ]
# use conditions for MYSQL query as appropriate
```

Comment: where is something like this for postgres??